# Wowza + Flex not reproducing whole audio

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, recording, wowza

I'm writing a flex app, which must record an audio and then playback. It records just fine, I can hear the flv on the server, but when it comes to the playback it cuts the end a little bit, and each time I ask to reproduce again it cuts a little bit more. What can it be? I guess it's something related to buffer management, but I don't know exactly. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**: Here's the code I'm using to playback. It is called from a mediator:

```
        var streamPlayClient:Object = new Object();
        this.stream.client = streamPlayClient;
        streamPlayClient.onPlayStatus = function(infoObject:Object):void {
            if (infoObject.code == "NetStream.Buffer.Flush") {
                stopPlayback();
            }
        }

        this.stream.play("flv:" + this.streamName);
```

Comment: Can you provide code?  Do you know if the issue is with your recording missing part of the source?  Or with the playback not playing the full file?

Comment: added, I didn't know exactly what to paste, so if you're looking for something else, please let me know, as I can't paste the whole code...

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I have to handle the NetStream.Buffer.Empty event, instead of the NetStream.Play.Complete or the NetStream.Buffer.Flush.